# Undefined contants.ts API value

Tags: angular

I have a constant.ts file that exports the base API. When I try to import the constants file and use the base API, I get an undefined. Here is my code

```
Constants.ts

export class Constants {
  public static API_ENDPOINT: 'https://www.techiediaries.com/api/';
}

App.module.ts

 providers: [Constants],


Api.service.ts

import { Constants } from '../constants/constants';

getData() {
  console.log(Constants.API_ENDPOINT);
  return this.httpClient.get(Constants.API_ENDPOINT + 'data.json');
}
```

Comment: in case you add the constant to the providers you need to injected then you will have a instant of the calss so you need to remove the  static from the class like this `  public API_ENDPOINT = 'https://www.techiediaries.com/api/';
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring the type in constants.ts, not assigning it a value.

It should be

```
export class Constants {
  public static API_ENDPOINT = 'https://www.techiediaries.com/api/';
}
```

This is setting the value `'https://www.techiediaries.com/api/'` rather than declaring the type to be `'https://www.techiediaries.com/api/'`.

Edit:

You don't need to set it as a provider if you're calling it directly. And as the other answer states, if it is a constant, then you should export is as a constant.

Even better, add it to environment.ts and the related environment files.

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  API_ENDPOINT = 'https://www.techiediaries.com/api/'
};
```

Then you can call a different endpoint in each environment if you wish.

Comment: Updated my answer with a bit of extra info

Answer (score 1):

just another option like this instand of use a class object

*constants.ts*

```
export const ApiEndPoint = `https://www.techiediaries.com/api/`;
```

*Api.service.ts*

```
import { ApiEndPoint } from '../constants/constants';

getData() {
  console.log(Constants.API_ENDPOINT);
  return this.httpClient.get(ApiEndPoint+ 'data.json');
}
```

in case you want to get all contants

```
 import * as Constants  from '../constants/constants';
```